# Select a 'virtual' column if another column has a value or is null in a SQL view

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select ALWAYS a column in my view, and set it with CASES.
example:

```
SELECT isDone
,doneN

from...
```

I have to set isDone in this way:

```
if done is 1 isDone is 'yes'
if done is 0 isDone is 'no'
```

(doneN is a column from another table, isDone instead doesn't exist in other tables, so it's a "virtual" column)

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when doneN = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as isDoneN
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify whether 'done' will always be 0 or 1.  If there are more values or you want to catch other values, use something like this:

```
select (case when done = 1 then 'yes' 
             when done = 0 then 'no' 
             else '' end) as isDone 
, doneN
from ...
```

If the 'done' is constrained to be 0 or 1, you can use:

```
select (case when done = 1 then 'yes' 
             else 'np' end) as isDone 
, doneN
from ...
```